# How To Save Data According To The Seconds From Continuous Incoming Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I am new in AWS IoT, Amazon DynamoDB and AWS. I receive lots of data from my MQTT client. I can store them in AWS DynamoDB but actually I don't want to store all of them. (Imagine I am getting 10.000 data in 1 minute in real life. You would need to ignore some of them.) **For example; if I am receiving data per  second I just want to save the data in odd seconds.**
Same as this;

```
1st Second -> store the data in AWS DynamoDB 
2nd Second -> dont write to Database 
3rd Second -> store the data in AWS DynamoDB 
4th Second-> dont write to Database 
....
```

This is normally how my SQL looks like in AWS IoT rule to store the all data in AWS DynamoDB:

```
SELECT *, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM 'trucks/#'
```

To reach my goal I tried something like this:

```
SELECT *, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM 'trucks/#' WHERE timestamp%2=1
```

which means save the data if timestamp is odd. But it didn't work of course.

Do you have any idea about how to do it in AWS IoT rule? Is there a way to do it?
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *, timestamp() as timestamp FROM 'iot/topic' where timestamp()%2=1
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Also, my timestamp is in milisecond and I needed the get the 4th digit from the last. For example: 160390076**9**261. I did it like this in SQL: `SELECT *, timestamp() as timestamp FROM 'trucks4/#' where floor(((timestamp()%10000)/1000))%2=1` I hope it makes sense. @Kirk